# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Virtualbox and Two Network Interface Configuration with Internet Conection

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox, internet

i have a VirtualBox Machine running Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 on my  Laptop,
i have set on installation the configuration for Network Interface of the first network interface `enp0s3` in my Work to get Internet conection and make basic Setup of Server.
and it look like this on `50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
   ethernets:
      enp0s3:
         address:
         - 192.168.1.11/24
         gateway4: 192.168.1.1
         nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.2.2
      version: 2
```

Then when I got home, it occurred to me to advance the work, and for that I need to configure a second network card to get online the VM, with the first or second network card / Network interface, dynamically.

i try to configure the secundary network card with Fisical Wifi hardware in Virtual box like this and try to get it with internet working from the secundary Interface Network:

[image]

AND

[image]

then in the Server OS i try to config it like this in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: yes
```

and use `sudo netplan apply` to apply the config and reboot the server when end.

[image]

but i return i try to get a ping to 8.8.4.4 Google DNS to check conectivity and get this:

[image]

**what can I do or what is missing, so that the server can connect to the internet dynamically by either of the two network cards if a failure, it is obvious that being home card # 1 failed.**

Some Ask me for this info:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the output of `ip route` from inside the machine and `ip a` and `ip route` from the host after all the config is applied.

Comment: @Yaron "and ip route from the host " How would that host be Windows 10? Lan Ip Static and Wireles DHCP

Comment: @Yaron i add information of VM Server but i cant fin this on Widows 10 Host