# Possible ways to configure network interfaces

Tags: server, 18.04, network-manager

I have a series of questions, it is possible, I look for examples:

1. Set 2 network settings on the same card?
2. Establish 2 network configurations in Different Network Cards, with different configurations, and that the S.O determines at startup or in hot which has connectivity to internet and uses it has defaul.

i am trying to get a VM with ubuntu 18.04 server Working with 2 NIC and 2 diferent configuration, secundary connection is a backup Internet Connection, but the server internet only working with the first, when i unplug the first nic cable, VM lost Internet connection and dont connect via second NIC, i test the 2 network and have it working.

Realted POST: [Ubuntu Server 18.04 Virtualbox and Two Network Interface Configuration with Internet Conection](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177378/1000503)

Comment: Many, many things are possible. What do you want to accomplish? And how much complexity are you willing to accept?

Comment: Enough to solve this post: I have really searched the internet and my intellectual capacity is not enough to determine which path to apply. and if I recognize that there are many options but I cannot implement one and obtain the correct ones.

Comment: Link here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177378/ubuntu-server-18-04-virtualbox-and-two-network-interface-configuration-with-inte

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) - looks like you are asking about a solution to a problem instead of asking about the real problem. What problem do you have that will be solved by "2 network settings on the same card"? For example, are you simply trying to get a VM or Container a separate IP address?

Comment: i am trying to get a VM with ubuntu 18.04 server Working with 2 NIC and 2 diferent configuration, secundary connection is a backup Internet Connection, but the server internet only working with the first, when i unplug the first nic cable, VM lost Internet connection and dont connect via second NIC, i test the 2 network and have it working.

Comment: USE 2 network settings on the same card; I thought that if it could be done it could work for the purpose explained above.